# State is not updating in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When i am trying to update the state of react component from an api call in componentwillmount function it is not working as expected. The value is not getting set.

```
export default class ListOfProducts extends Component {
        componentWillMount() {
            console.log('component currently mounting');
            fetchOrder().then(data => {
                console.log('order api call has been finished.', data);
                this.setState(data, function() {
       //this should print new data but i am still getting old data 
                    console.log('current this.state.', this.state.orders)
                })
            })
        }
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                "orders": {
                    "order_items": []
                }
            };
        }
        render() {
            let productList = [];
            let productUnit = (
                <View>
          {this.state.orders.order_items.map(function(order,i){
            return <ProductListItem
              delivered={true}
              productSKU={3}/>
          })}
          </View>
            );
            return productUnit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can modify the state directly in componentWillMount because the component is not rendered yet it doesn't make sense to call setState or make a call to setState is componentDidMount

Comment: even this.state= data is not working

Comment: @RakeshYadav You shouldn't manually set any values to `this.state` as they will be overridden when you call `setState()`.

Comment: @Barry127 you can update the state directly in componentWillMount. See this: The componentWillMount() is a chance for us to handle configuration, update our state, and in general prepare for the first render. At this point, props and initial state are defined. We can safely query this.props and this.state, knowing with certainty they are the current values. From: [here](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/premounting_with_componentwillmount.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform any asynchronous requests, I suggest you perform them in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. This is the suggested path based on the [Reactjs documentation for `componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount).

> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately
>   after the initial rendering occurs. At this point in the lifecycle,
>   you can access any refs to your children (e.g., to access the
>   underlying DOM representation). The componentDidMount() method of
>   child components is invoked before that of parent components.
>
> If you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks, set timers
>   using setTimeout or setInterval, or send AJAX requests, perform those
>   operations in this method.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you need to change:
"  extends Component { "
to
" extends React.Component { "

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. When you post an answer, be confident it will solve the issue. If you are unsure and still want to post your idea, try to describe why you think it can sole the problem. Good luck!